# Make the UIView Auto resize after Hiding some elements from the view

Tags: iphone

I am Having a Subview Which Needs to be resize after Hiding some Elements from this Subview

i can do this by setting the Frame but i wants to use the class property **autoresizesSubviews**

so can anybody help me how to use this with a example .

I am Using in this way 
But it is Not Working

```
[lbl setHidden:TRUE];
[txt setHidden:TRUE];
[txt setHidden:TRUE];
 addView.autoresizesSubviews=TRUE;
[self.view addSubview:addView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, If you are aware of the frame size, you can make use of UIView's **bound** or **frame** properties

Answer (score 0):

```
addView.autoresizingMask = mask;
```

mask is type of **UIViewAutoresizing**

it's my definition,

```
#define FlexibleT                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
#define FlexibleB                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
#define FlexibleL                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
#define FlexibleR                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
#define FlexibleH                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
#define FlexibleW                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

#define FixedMarginT                    FlexibleW | FlexibleB 
#define FixedMarginB                    FlexibleW | FlexibleT 
#define FixedMarginL                    FlexibleH | FlexibleR
#define FixedMarginR                    FlexibleH | FlexibleL
#define FixedHorizental                    FlexibleW | FlexibleT | FlexibleB
#define FixedVertical                   FlexibleH | FlexibleL | FlexibleR 
#define FixedALL                        FlexibleW | FlexibleH
#define FixedCenter                     FlexibleL | FlexibleR | FlexibleT | FlexibleB
```

you may set like this

```
addView.autoresizingMask = FixedVertical;
```